# Spark (1.4.0) stream running indefinitely during startup

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

- I am trying to get twitter stream using TwitterUtils api of Spark (v1.4.0). Connection is getting established properly but not able to see tweets in console instead **below Info/Warn messages are repeating in console indefinitely***

> 2015-06-22 09:21:52.844  INFO 6456 --- [      Thread-40] org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore     : ensureFreeSpace(13598) called with curMem=45830, maxMem=1017800294
>   2015-06-22 09:21:52.845  INFO 6456 --- [      Thread-40] org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore     : Block input-0-1434945112600 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 13.3 KB, free 970.6 MB)
>   2015-06-22 09:21:52.847  INFO 6456 --- [lt-dispatcher-2] o.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo  : Added input-0-1434945112600 in memory on localhost:50335 (size: 13.3 KB, free: 970.6 MB)
>   2015-06-22 09:21:52.852  WARN 6456 --- [      Thread-40] org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager    : Block input-0-1434945112600 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
>   2015-06-22 09:21:52.862  INFO 6456 --- [      Thread-40] o.a.s.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator  : Pushed block input-0-1434945112600
>   ...

Below is my RDD definitions

```
final JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> receiverStream = TwitterUtils
            .createStream(streamingSC);

    final JavaDStream<String> statuses = receiverStream
            .map(new TwitterStatusStream());

    final JavaDStream<String> lines = statuses
            .flatMap(new TwitterLineFunction());
    final JavaDStream<String> words = lines
            .flatMap(new TwitterWordFunction());

    final JavaDStream<String> hashTags = words
            .filter(new TwitterHashTagFunction());

    // statuses.print();
    hashTags.print();
    streamingSC.start();
    streamingSC.awaitTermination();
```

In below function I printed logger which is not showing in console..

```
public class TwitterStatusStream implements Function<Status, String>,
    Serializable {
public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TwitterStatusStream.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6529156421224365069L;

@Override
public String call(Status status) {
    String str = status.getText();
    logger.info(str);
    return str;
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...
Java Spark context creation and Java streaming context creation

```
public JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext() {
    return new JavaSparkContext(getSparkConf());
}
@Bean
public JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext() {
    return new JavaStreamingContext(javaSparkContext(),
            Durations.seconds(2000));
}

private SparkConf getSparkConf() {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("TwitterSpark");
    conf.setMaster(master);
    conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "512m");
    conf.set("spark.cores.max", "3");
    conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "1");
    return conf;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the command that you use to run the streaming application?

Comment: Also the part where you are creating the streaming context & the spark context.

Comment: @Sathish - It's spring boot project which is running spark. @ Holden Edited with code to create JavaStreaming context

Comment: the only thing that i wanted to verify is that, do you have enough receivers? For example, if you just run the Spark in local mode or local with only one core option, then you maynot see any output in the console.

Comment: Also, look at this issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4206

Comment: @Sathish _ am running it on 4 core system and mentioned spark master attribute as "local[6]"... conf I have set as above. Do you see any discrepancy in that conf?

Comment: Any update please.. I'm stucked on the same. Is this a open bug in spark-twitter connectivity?